# sharepoint error : A Project Item with the following item ID could not be found

Tags: sharepoint

when deploying SharePoint solution I am getting this error.where this id comes from. I checked web.config file but could not find any solution.Please help

Comment: Can you show the code where the error occurs?

Comment: It is not coding error.After building the solution when i am deploying this error comes up.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens when you have an unknow item in a feature or in a package in your Visual Studio Project.

Delete this item (generally put forward in red color) and you'll have the ability to package your wsp again.